# Extract Matrix columns and store them in individual vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, extract

I have a A matrix of size MxN where M is large and N is around 30.

```
[A,B,C,...,AD] = A(:,1:30)
```

The reason I am asking that is that I would like to give the columns a specific name (here A,B a,c,...,AD) and not being force to write:

```
[A,B,C,...,AD] =  deal(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),...,A(:,30))
```

Comment: does the vectors have to be individual or is making a table an option?

Comment: That's the point, they must be individual.

Comment: But... if you put them all in their own variables, you can't use `bsxfun`! :-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually better to keep all columns together in the matrix and just access them through their column index.

Anyway, if you really need to separate them into variables, you can convert the matrix to a cell array of its columns with [`num2cell`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), and then generate a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) to be used in the right-hand side of the assignment. Note also that in recent Matlab versions you can [remove `deal`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html):

```
A = magic(3); % example matrix
Ac = num2cell(A, 1);
[c1 c2 c3] = Ac{:}; % or [c1 c2 c3] = deal(Ac{:});
```

Answer (score 0):

For generating that lexicographical sequence I recently, out of ignorance, wrote this

```
Data = rand(2,671);
r = rem(size(Data,2),26);
m = floor(size(Data,2)/26);
Alf = char('A'+(0:25)'); %TeX-like char seq

if m == 0
    zzz = Alf(1:r);
else
    zzz = Alf;
    for x = 1:m-1
        zzz = char(zzz,[char(Alf(x)*ones(26,1)),Alf]);
    end
    if r > 0
        zzz = char(zzz, [char(Alf(m+1)*ones(r,1)),Alf(1:r)] );
    end
end
```

Depending on the number of columns it generates column names until `ZZ`. Please let me know if there is a readily made command for this in matlab.

---

You would **never ever use `eval` for such things!!! `eval` use is dangerous and wrong** (but you can't resist):

```
% ========== 
% Assign Data to indices
% ==========

for ind = 1:size(Data,2)
    eval([zzz(ind,:) '= Data(:,' num2str(ind) ');']);
end
```

and your workspace looks like an alphabet soup.